# What is the equivalent of packages.debian.org for CentOS?

Tags: centos, centos5

I have a CentOS machine that is not connected directly to the internet. I need to install some packages manually. If this were Debian I would go to packages.debian.org, search for the package and download it from the official repository. I am new to CentOS and can't find what the equivalent approach would be. The results in my Google searchs were from third party sites, I am looking for the official packages.

To be clear, I need to download individual packages in a webbrowser, not ISOs and without using yum.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such official site, however, you can view the repositories (found in /var/cache/yum/base/mirrorlist.txt) in a webbrowser.

For example, http://mirror.stanford.edu/yum/pub/centos/5.5/os/x86_64/CentOS/ lists all 64bit packages of CentOS 5.5 hosted by Stanford University.

There's a repository called [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL), maintained by the community behind Fedora, with some extra packages.
They use a web tool called repoview to show their packages. It's more pleasant than just staring at a list of package names, and provides descriptions for each package.

Check it out at http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/x86_64/repoview/ .

Comment: He's looking for a browseable/searcheable web page

Answer (score 1):

You can look for RPM packages in http://rpmfind.net it's a very good complete repository

Comment: Is there no official CentOS site?

Comment: No official site, this one helps you not only to find the official fedora and redhat packages but also the EPEL packages as kenny_r xplains

Answer (score 1):

check out http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/i386/CentOS/ and http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/ you can find all the centos packages of different architectures in these url's.