# CentOS / RHEL equivalent to packages.debian.org

Tags: centos, debian, redhat, yum

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the equivalent of packages.debian.org for CentOS?](https://serverfault.com/questions/225125/what-is-the-equivalent-of-packages-debian-org-for-centos)

When I want to search for packages for my Debian box I use

http://www.debian.org/distrib/packages

It has a nice search and a page for each package with lots of details.

Is there a CentoOS (RHEL) equivalent?

Comment: Understand the pain. Though survival is not difficult if you use google and `yum search` smartly.

Comment: @lain This may be a duplicate but I asked it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RHEL has [Red Hat Network (RHN)](http://rhn.redhat.com), but this is only browsable if you have a valid support contract with Red Hat.

As far as I'm aware, the CentOS project do not have a web interface to their Yum repositories, only automatic indexes generated by the web server.

[EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) has a web interface called repoview, but this is more or less equivalent to an automatic index generated by Apache, with the addition of showing package groups. There is no search facility.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if there is, but http://rpm.pbone.net/ is what I use.